# how many dynos i need for my application with Heroku?

Tags: heroku

we want to migrate my application to Heroku acctually we have 3 applications related and we want to move to Heroku. But we don't know how many dynos we need for deploy those applications. wether 3 applications in the same dynos and make a copy in other dynos or for each application one dynos? thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

If they are 3 separate applications you will need a minimum of 3 dynos since each Heroku application will need to run a dyno.

As to how many dynos each of your application needs to run that all depends on how busy each site is and how long requests take to process.

Answer (score 0):

I can only speak for Java and an embedded server/container. In this case you actually could deploy more than one app into your container (which will be startet from your dyno), only using one dyno.